# ajax call status is 200 but it is not successfull

Tags: asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I working on mvc asp.net project. I call my controller function with ajax, the call status is 200 but it is not successful, and goes to error section.

service:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TeamDto>> GetAllTeamsList()
        {
            var teams = await _teamRepository.GetAll().Include(u => u.Users).ThenInclude(m => m.User).ToListAsync();
            return ObjectMapper.Map<IEnumerable<TeamDto>>(teams);
        }
```

Controller:

```
  public  async Task<IEnumerable<TeamDto>> GetTeams()
        {
            var teams = await _teamAppService.GetAllTeamsList();
            return teams;
        }
```

js file:

```
  $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/App/Team/GetTeams",
            success: function (data) {
        ///
            },
            error: function (data) { console.log("it went bad " + JSON.stringify(data)); }
        });
```

Error:
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

this is what I get when copy the url in the browser:

> {"result":[{"tenantId":1,"name":"admin
> team","users":[{"tenantId":1,"userId":2,"teamId":58,"user":{"profilePictureId":null,"shouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin":false,"signInTokenExpireTimeUtc":null,"signInToken":null,"googleAuthenticatorKey":null,"pin":"1234","hourlyRate":0.00,"payrollId":"","warehouseId":1,"tandaUser":null,"normalizedUserName":"ADMIN","normalizedEmailAddress":"ADMIN@DEFAULTTENANT.COM","concurrencyStamp":"bd7ee91e-587b-4ae2-bc97-be2ce7d7789b","tokens":null,"deleterUser":null,"creatorUser":null,"lastModifierUser":null,"authenticationSource":null,"userName":"admin","tenantId":1,"emailAddress":"admin@defaulttenant.com","name":"admin","surname":"admin","fullName":"admin
> admin","password":"AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAENfcSE+zBppFKVxKUynGBiy4WZgDU3C3gbbWnQUdEyBb5J/S0uLkcqk+2MwM0DXxjw==","emailConfirmationCode":null,"passwordResetCode":null,"lockoutEndDateUtc":null,"accessFailedCount":1,"isLockoutEnabled":true,"phoneNumber":"","isPhoneNumberConfirmed":false,"securityStamp":"07a4d582-7233-3fbc-f3f7-39f015ee388b","isTwoFactorEnabled":false,"logins":null,"roles":null,"claims":null,"permissions":null,"settings":null,"isEmailConfirmed":true,"isActive":true,"isDeleted":false,"deleterUserId":null,"deletionTime":null,"lastModificationTime":"2020-09-30T02:54:34.402372Z","lastModifierUserId":null,"creationTime":"2019-09-05T23:27:47.8514365Z","creatorUserId":null,"id":2},"team":{"tenantId":1,"name":"admin
> team","users":[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the developer tools and look at the URL it is trying to request.  Normally in the context of the application, you don't have the /App defined.  In fact, you can use ASP.NET MVC Url helper to get the action method, to make sure the path is correct:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("GetTeams", "Team")",
```

Also, normally you would return data via JSON from the controller like:

```
  public  async Task<IEnumerable<TeamDto>> GetTeams()
  {
      var teams = await _teamAppService.GetAllTeamsList();
      return Json(teams, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

And maybe that would make a difference, using Json() from the asp.net mvc controller.  Note AllowGet ensures that GET requests on an action returning JSON works, otherwise it will be blocked and return an error.